# How build Android project using AirPush in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

How build Android project using AirPush in IntelliJ-Idea?
In eclipse all ok!
I'm insert my airpush jar file into "Libraries" (in Project Structure) and check "Export" in "Modules" (in Project Structure). But this not work. :-(

Comment: Any details? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Project bulding ok, but AirPush not show.

Answer (score 2):

copy airpush jar to libs folder then right click on jar and select add as library. it works for me.